# On page load populate a div .class with image

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I am trying to load an image as a placeholder into a DIV when the page loads.

Using the same image as a placeholder for the entire site, I simply want this almost as a background image, BUT when using that solution, it is not responsive and I need that DIV element to be responsive as it currently is now.

My div is set up as:

```
<div class='image_result'></div>
```

I have tried a few solutions but with no success.

Comment: You're missing your code.

Comment: yup that was my bad!

Comment: Background images can most certainly be responsive - see `background-size`. You can even change images at different breakpoints.

Comment: I understand that, but the DIV needs to be 800px tall x 600px wide on desktop, and change in proportion no matter what to width:100% and height auto (proportionate). Not as simple as just loading an image into that DIV I don't believe, I may be wrong. I could give the initial div a width but giving it a height won't change it with just a simple background image if users do not populate the DIV from the form at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the appropriate version of `background-size`, you can achieve your desired result. There's a cool and under-appreciated trick of using percentage based padding-top to have a proportionally responsive div. Since 800x600 has a height-to-width ratio of 3/4 (or 75%) you can use that as your padding:

```
.image_result {
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 75%;
}
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/nowk62b6/1/
>   **NOTE:** In the fiddle, resize your screen until the blue box is 800px wide.

You can use your imagination on how to enable/disable this extra padding before and after your content loads. You can also put that in a media query so that it only takes affect when the screen is smaller than 800px.

```
.image_result {
  background-size: contain;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .image_result {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 75%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with background contain:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this one?

```css
    .image_result { 
      max-width:800px;
      max-height:600px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="image_result">
     <img src="http://www.tazzee.com/images/A_med_grey_lg.jpg" alt="" height="auto" width="100%"> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, thanks for the speedy replies. I found my solution using Ryan's suggestion with background-size. I needed the easiest way to implement this as a background image, then when a image loaded to that div to take it's place, which I have achieved here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/hc969u9j/

```
.image_result {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    background: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?   txtsize=33&txt=BG%20Image%20Here&w=800&h=600) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Appreciate your help and feedback! I hope this method helps anyone else out in the future. Thanks Ryan Wheale.

Mike

Comment: The way to show your appreciation is to click the checkmark next to the answer that helped you ;)